# Replacing Segment with mod rewrite in .htacces

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to change this URL:

```
domain.com/?ACT=52&id=28
```

to this one:

```
domain.com/site.html
```

I want to replace the last segment `?ACT=52&id=28` to `site.html`. There are no parameters to consider. The URL `domain.com/?ACT=52&id=28` will always be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this in the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^ACT=52&id=28$
RewriteRule ^/?$ /site.html [L]
```

This makes it so when someone goes to `domain.com/?ACT=52&id=28`, they get served the content at `domain.com/site.html`, but if you to change the URL that's in the browser's URL address bar, you need to **REDIRECT**, not internally rewrite, so add the redirect flag in the square brackets: `[L,R]`